# new Date() return a day before the day in date time string in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, datetime-format

I have an existing date time string in place

```
new Date('2014-08-01T00:00:00')
```

But instead of returning 2014-08-01, it returns as 2014-07-31 in the actually angularJS view.

I wonder is this date time string valid, if not, why its not valid.

**Could the `T` be the reason that the string return a wrong date?**

The console.log return a date of `Thu Jul 31 2014 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

Thank You

**Lets call those -2 are toxic vote downs. They should really recall the days when they are struggling to understand the basic concepts that now apparant to them. Its a shame.**

Comment: Your timezone might be messing with the returned result. What is the returned date's time?

Comment: The displayed date uses your browser timezone.

Comment: How are you using it in your Angular view?

Comment: **Do not use the Date constructor to parse strings**. That format string (i.e. ISO 8601 without timezone) will be parsed as UTC in most modern browsers, local in Chrome and fail completely in IE 8 and lower. (BTW, down voters who can't be bothered to explain their actions are plain lazy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present (Autumn 2014), JavaScript's date/time format diverges from ISO-8601 in a very important way: If there's no timezone indicator on the string, it assumes `Z` ("Zulu", GMT).

So

```
new Date('2014-08-01T00:00:00')
```

...is August 1st at midnight GMT. If you live east of GMT, that will be on the 31st in your local time.

**However**, this incompatibility with ISO-8601 is being fixed in ES6 and some implementations (including the latest V8 in Chrome) are already updating it. The ES6 spec changes the default to local time; check out §20.3.1.15 ("Date Time String Format", the section number may change) in the [draft PDFs](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) or [this unofficial HTML version](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format).

Comment: May I know what is the `T` (in between date n time) in this case mean?

Comment: @Chen: It's just to separate the time from the date; `T` stands for "time". JavaScript got it from ISO-8601 (even though, again, JavaScript's format is **not** ISO-8601), which used it to avoid having spaces in the string.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—that is true according to ES5, but the [*ES6 draft*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format) changes to be consistent with ISO 8601 where dates without a timezone are local. Chrome has already implemented it.

Comment: @RobG: **Wow**, I did not expect them to change that. I thought they'd diverged on purpose, because of widespread implementations in the wild. But sure enough! I guess it was just a mistake, or the incompatibility bothered people too much. BTW: Thanks for the link, I didn't know about that unofficial HTML version and have just been downloading the massive PDFs... :-)

Answer (score 4):

The displayed date uses the timezone of your browser/computer. This means that if you are in GMT-1 and you enter `2014-08-01T00:00:00`, the actual date is `2014-08-01T00:00:00 - 1 hour` = `2014-07-31T23:00:00`

Comment: ...or what T.J Crowder said... his explanation is way better ^_^

Comment: I actually think your answer helped me as well to show an example. You two are compliment answers. hard to choose which is the best gosh.... But since Crowder got more detail, I will vote on his. However, your answer is GREAT as well! vote up for u!

Answer (score 0):

I have this date in startdate=2021-10-27T00:00:00-04:00,
d=new Date(data.StartDate) // outputTue Oct 26 2021 23:00:00 GMT-0500
But date is getting one day before'Tue Oct 26 2021 23:00:00 GMT-0500' in central timezone(below -6,-7,-8...).

Actually I used this it is working fine but for central timezone not working
var d = new Date(data.StartDate);
console.log(data.startDate);
$scope.txtStartDate = ("0" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + d.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + d.getFullYear();

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).